# How to do Elastic search special character search using boolquery builder

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, special-characters, java-11

I'm using BoolqueryBuilder for searching values with java spring boot backend.
And I need to search in elastic search values with special characters Like '@#$%test test search'

- Is there any way to fetch search values with querystring / matchquery / wildcard.
- My elastic search index name is document. and field name is value
- Is it needed to create custom analyzer for this search to happen.
- Also it shouldn't affect normal text and numerical search And it should be case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can search your data

```
PUT index_name/_doc/1
{
  "field_name": "@#$%test test search"
}

GET index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "field_name",
      "query": "(@#)*"
    }
  }
}
```

Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters

---

The above method is not the best one, so I want to give more information and explain how you can search your data more efficiently. In the below picture, you will see how elasticsearch standard analyze **works both during indexing and searching.**
[image]

If you don't need an analyzer (probably you don't need it in your scenario) you can use [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) field type which is not analyzed.

When you index the document as a string in Elasticsearch, ECS will automatically create 2 fields for each string, one of which will be named field_name of text type and the other will be named field_name.keyword of keyword type.
Here is an example:

```
PUT index_name/_doc/1
{
  "field_name": "@#$%test test search"
}

GET index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "field_name.keyword": "@#$*"
    }
  }
}

GET index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "field_name.keyword",
      "query": "@#*%* AND *test*"
    }
  }
}
```

---

[case insensitive](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html)

```
GET index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "field_name.keyword": {
        "value": "*TesT*",
        "case_insensitive": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to have case insensitive to query_string?
Currently if i search for %test no results are coming, but there are messages with %Test.

Comment: Try this:
   "query_string" : {"query" : "ABC", analyzer: "standard"}